# tkinter, < not supported between instances of 'IntVar' and 'int'

Tags: python, tkinter

In python using tkinter. I'm trying to let a user enter a number into an entry box, the number they enter will be the number a loop starts on. An error appears saying: *TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'IntVar' and 'int'*.

```
root = tk.Tk()
x = tk.IntVar(value=1)


EnterNumber = tk.Label(root, text='Starting server:')
EnterNumber.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas.create_window(100, 680, window=EnterNumber)
Message = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=x)
canvas.create_window(232, 680, height=40, width=50, window=Message)


def Typing():
    time.sleep(5)
    global x
    while x < 212 and not keyboard.is_pressed("q"): #error is here
        pyautogui.moveTo(Search)
        click()
        X = str(x)
        s = "smalltribes"
        S = str(s)
        U = " "
        T = S+X+U
        pyautogui.write(T)
        time.sleep(1)
        x += 1
```

Not all of the code is included just what I thought is needed.

Comment: do not use `sleep()` while also using tkinter. Instead use `after()` from tkinter's library to manage time delays. Sleep in this case will freeze up tkinter all together instead of simply providing a delay in your while loop. Also using a while loop here is also no preferable. With a combination of a well written function and the `after()` method you can perform this loop without locking up tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `x.get()` wherever you are trying to compare the value of `x` to something. That is how you get the value that is stored in a `tkinter` custom variable.